# is it safe to pass an exception object reference to a new exception object?

Tags: c++, exception

suppose the following:

```
struct wrapper_exception {
std::runtime_error& err;
  wrapper_exception( std::runtime_error& _e ) : err(e) {}
}; 

try {

throw std::runtime_error("foo");

} catch (std::runtime_error& err) {

 throw wrapper_exception( err);
}
```

question: **Is it safe to access the reference to runtime_error inside wrapper_exception after it is handled?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm very tempted to say that this is undefined behavior.

The standard says repeatedly that the lifetime of the exception objects ends when the active handler exits *other than by rethrowing the exception*, i.e. by saying `throw;`.

Since you do not rethrow the exception, the original exception object expires at the end of the catch block and you end up with a dangling reference, no different from throwing an object that holds a reference to a local variable.

Comment: This would be my interpretation as well.  An alternative may be to use Boost Exception as documented here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/exception/doc/tutorial_enable_error_info.html - that is, to let Boost help you copy the original exception and add extra pieces of information to it, rather than the OP's wrapper implementation.

Comment: I also think this is the correct interpretation. C++11 does add an exception_ptr and some speciality classes  which handle rethrow distinctly. However, not using those classes only a `throw` can preserve the original exception.